# Vuex Modules Creating Nested Object

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex

I have been trying to separate my store.js file into multiple store modules. I have it working (somewhat), but it also created kind of a big issue.

In my initial one single file store, let's suppose this is my state object:

```
state: { user: '' }
```

And the output in the Vuex developer tools shows the user object as it should:

```
User: { name: "John", age: 33 }
```

But after splitting the the store into modules the user object in the Vuex developer tools is as follows:

```
User: { User: { name: "John", age: 33 } }
```

So it creates a new object using the name I give it in the modules object and import in the main store.js file, which then contains the "true" user object.

Is there any way to have it not create a new object and keep it the same as if the entire store lived inside the store.js file?

-Sergio

**EDIT:**

Here is the structure of my files:

`store
   store.js
   modules
      user.js`

The code in the modules/user.js:

```
const state = { User: '' }
const mutations = { ... }
const actions = { ... }
export default { state, mutations, actions }
```

The code in my store.js

```
import User from './modules/user';
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
   modules: {
      User
   }
});
```

Prior to externalizing the store I would get in Vuex dev tools:
`User: { name: "John", age: 33 }`
After externalizing the store I get:
`User: { User: { name: "John", age: 33 } }`

It's nesting `User` from the `modules/user` file inside the `User` in the store.js file. I want to avoid that (if its possible) so that I don't have to change everything in my components/template files.

Comment: But how are you doing this assignment?

Comment: Hi Hamilton, I don't understand your question...can you please rephrase.

Comment: At what point in time do you do this assignment? And how is this assignment being done? Are you calling this assignment more than once?

Comment: I have updated my initial question, hope it clarifies more.

Comment: Are you assigning the user again in vuex, or are you doing this yourself?

Comment: The user is being assigned in the `modules/user` file.

Answer (score 0):

The 'extra parent object' shown in the Vue Devtools is actually the ***namespaced*** module. If you set the User module's `namespace` attribute to `false`, the User state will no longer be placed within a namespaced object and will instead be

> registered under the **global namespace**. ([Vuex Namespacing](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing))

Setting `namespace: false` is totally fine if you don't expect User function names to conflict with other modular state function names.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    User: {
      namespaced: false,
      state: { user: '' },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```